# How to use Scala macros to create new partial functions or transform them?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes, partial-functions

I am having trouble writing a macro that transforms a given partial function and creates a new partial function. For instance, I want to be able to decompose the given partial function into its elements - pattern binder, guard condition, and body; then I want to decompose the pattern binder and the guard condition into smaller pieces and reassemble new partial functions out of these pieces. However, I am getting strange errors at macro expansion that I can't debug.

The simplest problem that gives the same error is the code that decomposes the given partial function into the binder, the guard, and the body, and reassembles it back into the same partial function.

I can do this with a simple type `PartialFunction[Int,Any]` but not with types that involve case classes, `PartialFunction[MyCaseClass,Any]`.

Here is the code that works and the code that doesn't.

**Working code**: take a partial function, destructure it using quasiquotes, assemble the same function again, and return it.

```
package sample

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object MacroTest {
  type Simple = PartialFunction[Int, Any]

  def no_problem(pf: Simple): Simple = macro no_problemImpl
  def no_problemImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(pf: c.Expr[Simple]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val q"{ case $binder  => $body }" = pf.tree
    q"{ case $binder  => $body }"
  }
}
```

This macro compiles and tests pass:

```
import MacroTest._

val testPf: Simple = { case x => x + 1 }
testPf(2) shouldEqual 3 // passes

  // now do the same with macro:
val result = no_problem({ case x => x + 1 })
result(2) shouldEqual 3 // passes
```

**Non-working code**: Exactly the same macro except for using a case class instead of `Int` as the argument of a partial function.

```
case class Blob(left: Int, right: Int)

type Complicated = PartialFunction[Blob, Any]

def problem(pf: Complicated): Complicated = macro problemImpl
def problemImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(pf: c.Expr[Complicated]) = {
    import c.universe._

    val q"{ case $binder  => $body }" = pf.tree
    q"{ case $binder  => $body }"
}
```

The code is *exactly the same*, only the type is different (`Complicated` instead of `Simple`).

The macro code compiles, but the test fails to compile (fails at macro expansion):

```
val blob = Blob(1,2)
val testPf: Complicated = { case Blob(x, y) => x + y }
testPf(blob) shouldEqual 3 // passes

  // now try the same with macro:
val result = problem({ case Blob(x, y) => x + y })
  // compile error when compiling the test code: 
Could not find proxy for case val x1: sample.Blob in List(value x1, method applyOrElse, <$anon: Function1>, value result, method apply, <$anon: Function0>, value <local MacroTestSpec>, class MacroTestSpec, package sample, package <root>) (currentOwner= value y )
```

I have simplified the problem to the barest minimum possible that still fails. In my actual code, the types are more complex, the partial functions may have guards, and I do transform the code of the partial function by rearranging its arguments and guards. I can sometimes make the transformation work when the guards are absent, but not when the argument of the partial function is a case class. Perhaps the presence of guards is not the root of the problem: the problem happens when there is a compound type with `unapply` somewhere. I get essentially the same error message as I get with this drastically simplified example shown above.

I cannot seem to solve this problem despite having tried many alternative ways of transforming the partial function:

- Use whitebox macro context
- Use plain quasiquotes, as in the examples shown above
- Use special quasiquotes for cases and patterns `cq"..."`, `pq"..."` and `q"{case ..$cases}"` as shown in the documentation for quasiquotes
- Matching with guard: `q"{case $binder if $guard => $body }"`, also with `cq` and `pq` quasiquotes
- Adding `c.typecheck` or `c.untypecheck` at various places (this used to be called `resetAllAttrs`, which is now deprecated)
- Use no quasiquotes but do everything in raw syntax trees: use `Traverser` with raw tree matching, such as `case UnApply(Apply(Select(t@Ident(TermName(_)), TermName("unapply")), List(Ident(TermName("<unapply-selector>")))), List(binder)) if t.tpe <:< typeOf[Blob]` and so on
- Try to replace `Ident`'s in the pattern matcher by `Ident`'s taken from the guard condition, and vice versa (this gives weird errors, "assertion failed", due to failed typechecking)
- Use `Any` instead of the specific types, returning `PartialFunction[Any,Any]`, or a total function `Function1[Blob,Any]` and so on
- Use a type parameter `T` instead of `Blob`, parameterizing the macro and accepting `PartialFunction[T,Any]`

I would appreciate any help! I am using Scala 2.11.8 with straight macros (no "macro paradise").

Comment: `{ case x@Blob(aaa: Int, bbb: Int) => x.left + x.right  }` this is work , also i do not why -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're hitting a long standing issue in the Scala compiler. Typechecking is not *idempotent* in several cases, specifically extractors using `unapply`: [SI-5465](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5465). There is no easy solution for this, but I can suggest two workarounds. Let me first explain the problem briefly.

#### The problem with def macros and typechecking

Def macros are expanded during the typechecking phase. As a consequence arguments to def macros are typed trees. Returning a *well-typed* or *untyped* tree is acceptable. However, returning a *partially typed* (your case) or *ill-typed* tree is very likely to trip the compiler, causing a typechecking error at best or an error in a subsequent phase. Note that quasiquotes generate *untyped* trees. How can these bad trees occur?

- **Partially typed trees** - usually by wrapping *untyped* code around the *typed* arguments or replacing parts of them with *untyped* code. In many cases you can get away with those, but not always.
- **Ill-typed trees** - by rearranging the *typed* arguments in a way that invalidates the original type information, e.g. splicing one argument into another. These will surely cause a problem.

#### Workarounds

Hopefully you can see that the problem is conceptual and deeply rooted. But you can take one of two approaches to solve the problem:

1. **The hacky solution** - do a roundtrip through a String representation of the final result:

   ```
   c.parse(showCode(q"{ case $binder  => $body }"))
   ```

   `showCode` will usually print parseable code, even when `untypecheck` is not idempotent. Of course this will incur some compile time performance overhead, which may or may not be acceptable for your use case.
2. **The hard solution** - manually typecheck the glue code by using internal compiler APIs. I can't explain how to do this in one post, but you would have to learn all about types, symbols and their owners. The worst part is that trees are *mutable* wrt type information. If you go that route, I recommend going through the source code of [scala/async](https://github.com/scala/async).

The best thing to do is probably avoid writing macros or wait until the semantic API of `scala.meta` is released and you can use it for def macros.

Comment: So the easy solution would be either one of the two options: 1) untypecheck all macro arguments before manipulating them (at the risk of losing some needed type information?), or untypecheck just the final tree before the macro returns it, 2) typecheck everything after each quasiquote used inside the macro? Which one would work better?

Comment: What works so far: 1) write `c.untypecheck(q"...")` at the end of the macro body. This removes the error, and the macro works correctly. 2) Insert type annotations into the binders, and again untypecheck everything.

The take away from this exercise: it's best to avoid disassembling and reassembling an expression tree. A macro should either create a completely new expression tree, or do limited search-and-replace on an existing valid expression tree, rearranging its existing elements. It's error-prone to add new pieces to an existing expresion tree.